# Dojo Stacked column chart issues in add total stacked value on the top of stacked

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I seem to be having a problem with my dojo stacked column chart. Each stack values are placed  "inside" the stacked chart. But I want these stacked totals should be at the top but outside the chart, just above the x axis labels. So How do I achieve where the stack totals are displayed just top the stacked columns . Here is my jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/B45PW/). Here i need to show my Total stacked value on the top of bar, as well as tooltip for each stacked value also.

Here is my code is

```
    require(["dojox/charting/Chart", 
      "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", 
   "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", 
   "dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns",
   "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
   "dojo/ready", 
   "dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend"],
   function(Chart, Lines, Default, StackedColumns, Tooltip, ready, SelectableLegend) {
ready(function() {
    var chart1 = new Chart("chart1");
    chart1.title = "stacked chart";
    chart1.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
        type: StackedColumns,
        gap:6,
        lines: true,
        areas: true,
        markers: true,
        labels: true,
        labelStyle:"inside",
        //maxBarSize: 35,
        tension: "2"
    });
chart1.addAxis("x", {  
                      dropLabels: false,
                      labelSizeChange: true,
                      rotation:-20,
                      majorTicks:true,
                      majorTickStep:1,
                      minorTicks:false,
                      font: "normal normal bold 12px Tahoma", 
                      fontColor: "black",
                     labels: [{"value":1,"text":"A"},{"value":2,"text":"B"},{"value":3,"text":"C"},{"value":4,"text":"D"},{"value":5,"text":"E"},{"value":6,"text":"F"}] 
});
    chart1.addAxis("y", {title:"Cost",
      fixLower: "major",
      fixUpper: "major", 
       includeZero: true,
      majorTickStep:500,
     max: 1500,
     //from:1000,
     //to:6000,
        vertical: true
    });

    chart1.addSeries("AC",[300,500,500,600,300,280] ,
     {

        plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
        stroke: {
            color: "#FFFFFF" ,

        },
        fill: "#FFAEAE "
    });
    chart1.addSeries("TV", [244,301,699,620,820,837], {
        plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
        stroke: {
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        fill: "#FFEC94"
    });
    chart1.addSeries("ACCE", [500,100,100,100,200,250] , {
        plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
        stroke: {
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        fill: "#B4D8E7"
    });
    chart1.addSeries("OTHER", [100,150,100,700,700,0,800,300,300] , {
        plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
        stroke: {
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        fill: "#56BAEC"
    });

   new Tooltip(chart1, "stackedColumnsPlot", {
        text: function(chartItem) {
            console.debug(chartItem);
        //return "Rating: " + chartItem.run.data[chartItem.index] + "; Total Value: " + chartItem.y;
          // return  "Comparision Rating: " + chartItem.y;
           return "Value: " + chartItem.run.data[chartItem.index] + "; Stacked Value: " + chartItem.y;
        }
    }); 

    chart1.render();

    new SelectableLegend({
        chart: chart1,
        horizontal: true,
        align:top
    }, "chart1SelectableLegend");
   });
  });
```

In my experience, when I have a series with first value: 300, and another with first value: 244, the tooltip shows static series name Value:300 and value: 244. when hovering over these series. I would like it to still show AC: 300 and TV: 244 with total stacked value show on the top of the stacked as Total: 544.
But I am unble to get this type of value .
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve in the end but you can definitely dislpay "AC: 300, TV: 244" by using the following text function:

```
        text: function(chartItem, plot) {
            return "AC: "+plot.series[0].data[chartItem.index] +
                ", TV: "+plot.series[1].data[chartItem.index];
        }
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/B45PW/3/

EDIT: In your example you are also missing the CSS needed for the tooltip to show up correctly. You need to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojoinstall/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
```

and use the claro class on your body:

```
<body class="claro">
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/B45PW/4/

Comment: Thanks for your  response. I want tooltip shows on mouse hover of the stacked series. But in your code it shows the values at same time and also bottom of the graph.I need it will show on mouse hover tooltips with respective series. And another is i want to show sum of all stacked values on the top of the bar.So please suggest me how it is possible.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.Its nice .But actually i need to show different different tooltips for different different series.But here all series values shows at a time.If i will mouse hover on AC series then it only shows AC: 300 and if mouse hover on TV series then it shows only TV:244. Need not to shows all series value simultaneously. And one thing tell me how can show my total stacked values (sum of AC+TV+OTHERS+ACCE)at the top of the bar .Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Christophe..kindly request to you solve my query. How can i show my total sum of stacked values on the top bar.

Comment: Please suggest me how it is possible.

Comment: please suggest me how can it is possible .